# Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter, arrow-functions

- I am trying handle below code and its showing
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxJnc.png)

```js
const toArray = props =>
  (props && props.split ? props.split(',') : props || []).map(item => item.trim());

const hasField = (entity, fields) => {
  if (!fields.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i + 1) {
    if (entity && entity.includes(fields[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

module.exports = (entities, query) => {
  const industries = toArray(query.industries);
  const technologies = toArray(query.technologies);
  const maturity = toArray(query.maturity);

  return entities.filter(function (entity) {
    const hasTecnology = hasField(entity.industries, industries);
    const hasIndustury = hasField(entity.technologies, technologies);
    const hasMaturity = hasField(entity.maturity, maturity);

    const condition = hasTecnology || hasIndustury || hasMaturity;

    if (condition) return entity;
  }, []);
};
```

- output showing:

---

23:26  error    Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of function
array-callback-return

---

- Line 23:26 is ==> module.exports = (entities, query) => {
- Could you please check this? What I wrongly doing here?

Comment: [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#description) expects a value to be returned from the callback which will be coerced to a boolean to evaluate whether to include the element in the result or not. You are either not returning or returning the element itself, just `return condition;` (if `true` the element will be kept if `false` it won't)

Comment: This is actually a linting error, not a javascript error. Filter will accept the default `undefined` when there is no explicit return.

Answer (score 2):

It's just as the error says - you're not always returning a value.

The callback return value only needs to be truthy or falsey. Change

```
if (condition) return entity;
```

to

```
return condition;
```